# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.utils'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I wanted to run my simple object detection program but I ran into this error

Im trying to run a python program that uses OWL-ViT and installed transformers for that
but it gives this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.utils" error

I installed it to virtual env if thats the problem

````
import requests
from PIL import Image
import torch

from transformers import OwlViTProcessor, OwlViTForObjectDetection
import os
fcontent = os.listdir("..\imgs")

processor = OwlViTProcessor.from_pretrained("google/owlvit-base-patch32")
model = OwlViTForObjectDetection.from_pretrained("google/owlvit-base-patch32")


def result(a):
    for imag in fcontent:
        image = Image.open(imag)
        texts = [[a]]
        inputs = processor(text=texts, images=image, return_tensors="pt")
        outputs = model(**inputs)

        # Target image sizes (height, width) to rescale box predictions [batch_size, 2]
        target_sizes = torch.Tensor([image.size[::-1]])
        # Convert outputs (bounding boxes and class logits) to Pascal VOC format (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
        results = processor.post_process_object_detection(outputs=outputs, target_sizes=target_sizes, threshold=0.1)
        i = 0  # Retrieve predictions for the first image for the corresponding text queries
        text = texts[i]
        boxes, scores, labels = results[i]["boxes"], results[i]["scores"], results[i]["labels"]
        for box, score, label in zip(boxes, scores, labels):
            box = [round(i, 2) for i in box.tolist()]
            print(f"Detected {text[label]} with confidence {round(score.item(), 3)} at location {box}")
```Heres my code
````

Comment: Welcome! Where is `transformers.utils` in your code? Please post the full code and imports.

Comment: It is probably used with that owlvit thingy. Also this is the only program that I use transformers in.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deste\OneDrive\Masaüstü\sea\aprogcopy\Hello.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ai import result
  File "C:\Users\deste\OneDrive\Masaüstü\sea\aprogcopy\ai.py", line 5, in <module>
    from transformers import OwlViTProcessor, OwlViTForObjectDetection
  File "C:\Users\deste\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>

Comment: from . import dependency_versions_check
  File "C:\Users\deste\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.utils'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the missing Python package?

```bash
pip install transformers
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the `transformers` from the pip, install it directly from GitHub. I encountered the same issue and thanks to this [discussion](https://huggingface.co/DiscoResearch/mixtral-7b-8expert/discussions/9), I got this problem solved.

```
pip uninstall -y transformers
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```